# Ruby / Watir : how to click on a disabled button (Watir::Exception::ObjectDisabledException)

Tags: ruby, github, watir, submit-button, disable

I want to make a program in Ruby that create a github repository. Everything is all right, but when i want to click the button 'create repository' after filling the repository name, nothing happened and the program stop with a timeout error.

This is the html code of the disabled button :

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary first-in-line" data-disable-with="Creating repository…" disabled="">
        Create repository
      </button>
```

And the html code of the enabled button :

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary first-in-line" data-disable-with="Creating repository…">
        Create repository
      </button>
```

And this my ruby program

```rb
repo_name = gets.chomp
repo = browser.text_field(id: 'repository_name')
repo.set(repo_name)

browser.driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 3

create_button = browser.button(type: "submit")
create_button.wait_until(&:enabled?).click
```

I'am pretty sure that my pb comes that when i'm landing on the page, the button is disabled, and even if i'm filling the repository_name input, my prog can't access to the button.

So do you have a solution about that ? Or maybe do you know if there is an other pb ?

Edit :

When here is the code without the waiting commands :

```rb
repo_name = gets.chomp
repo = browser.text_field(id: 'repository_name')
repo.set(repo_name)

create_button = browser.button(type: "submit").click
```

And when I run it, I'v got a 'Watir::Exception::ObjectDisabledException' error

```
("element present, but timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for #
<Watir::Button: located: true; {:type=>"submit", :tag_name=>"button"}> to be enabled (Watir::Exception::ObjectDisabledException)"
```

Comment: First off, you don't have to use implicit wait when you use WATIR. Second off, you don't have to wait explicitly to wait until button gets enabled because that too automatic in watir.  And atlast post the error message you are getting here.

Comment: Thank for the answer, I edit the post

Comment: Okay, Then element is disabled. Go through the same flow manually and check whether it is disabled .

Comment: When I check the website page that my program open, after filling the text_field area for the repo name, the button goes from disabled to enabled. But my program still can't click

Comment: Okay, let me check. But I can't do it today. Monday morning I can do.

Comment: okay no pb, thanks a lot !

Comment: FWIW: github has an API: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create

Comment: Hope you have gotten the better solution from orde!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think below code might work for you

```
browser.text_field(id: 'repository_name').set("repo_name")
browser.send_keys(:tab)
```

And as Justin mentioned in his answer, click the create repository button as below:

```
browser.button(type: "submit", visible: true).click
```

Comment: I think the button get enabled as soon as we shift focus out of the field. You can see this manually as well, while you're typing repo name the button is disabled but as soon as you click somewhere else, it gets enabled. I made changes in the answer, please try that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there are multiple submit buttons on the page. You can see this by retrieving a collection of buttons:

```
# Button text:
browser.buttons(type: 'submit').map(&:text_content)
#=> ["Set status", "Sign out", "Create repository"]

# Disabled status:
browser.buttons(type: 'submit').map(&:disabled?)
#=> [true, false, false]
```

`browser.button(type: "submit")` returns the first submit button on the page, which is the disabled "Set status" button.

The "Create repository" button is actually the last one on the page. A more specific locator for the button is required. Some options:

```
# By text
browser.button(text: 'Create repository')

# By visibility (since the other 2 are hidden by default)
browser.button(type: "submit", visible: true)
```